# XWiki on proxmox

Tags: xwiki, proxmox

I need to install XWiki on a server having Proxmox & I have no idea what container or VM do I use & how to make it possible for the team to work on the XWiki.

& Also I will have to make sure that the host of the XWiki is gonna have puppet agent for later configuration. (though I don't think it represents a problem)

Thank you for you help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you tries to run it as a Debian package, as explained here:  http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/InstallationViaAPT  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's just me, I am a beginner, on the server having **proxmox**, I created a container using **Ubuntu trusty** template, then I installed XWiki on it as in the official documentation [here](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/InstallationViaAPT) ,

I had to fix some problems with Tomcat as mentioned [here](http://capnjosh.com/blog/installing-xwiki-on-ubuntu-the-easy-way/)

then I just logged into XWiki with my machine browser through

> [Container_IP_Address]:8080/xwiki